# Flutter Firestore returning null (retrieve data from subcollection)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**What do I want it to do**
I want to fetch a list of the amount of photo's a user has stored in it's profile updated in realtime.
I want my code to fetch the links from a user profile but I am constantly getting an error. 
[image: Where I want to get it from]

**The value "Text("${document['link']}")" gives null.**

**What have I tried**
Read and applied every problem/solution on stackoverflow on this issue

**My code**
I already have another streambuilder which is used to fetch the names of the instances so that's where the other DocumentSnapshot is coming from. Now I just want a streambuilder which focusses on the pictures.

```
    Widget imageList(DocumentSnapshot document //I use this to fetch the current document ID) {
    print(_uploadedFileURL);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('Test')
          .document(document.documentID).collection('foto')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("Loading");
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                _imageList(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]));
      },
    );


 }

//Widget to show the Text but this returns null
    Widget _imageList(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
        return Card(
          child: prefix0.Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              prefix0.Text("${document['link']}")
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: what is prefix0?

Comment: Which value is unexpectedly null?

Comment: @lacas It sais prefix0 if that widget is already used. I should actually name it new "WidgetName".

Comment: @danh The value Text("${document['link']}" is null. I just can't seem to get data from that subcollection. I just want to have the links in a text widget.

Answer (score 0):

Get data from the doc snapshot with its data method...

```
prefix0.Text("${document.data()['link']}")
```

Comment: It errors: "'data' isn't a function" Same thing for the listviewbuilder inside the StreamBuilder it doesn't build 2 list items if there are 2 documents inside "foto" collection which contain the link to images.